# Running knife commands from Capistrano task

Tags: capistrano, bundler, chef-infra, knife

I'm attempting to configure the knife commandline tool via a capistrano task, and running into an issue when it hits the following line

```
system "knife configure --yes --defaults -s ... -c ... -u ... -r ..."
```

it says this

```
Could not find net-ssh-2.6.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I do have this gem installed and I believe it comes with chef.  I assume this has something to do with the environment that Capistrano runs in.

Comment: How did you install Chef: apt, gem, knife bootstrap?

Comment: @DracoAter gem, I'm on OSX

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Chef:

```
gem uninstall chef
```

And re-install it:

```
gem install chef
```